# Why does exp**2 produce the error "unsupported operand type(s) for **"?

Tags: python, typeerror

Why does this produce an error?

```
>>> from math import exp
>>> exp**2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exp**` must be either `exp` or `e**` (in the latter case, `from math import e`). `math.exp` is not the name for the constant `e`, but the exponential function.

```
>>> exp(2)
7.38905609893065
>>> from math import e
>>> e**2
7.3890560989306495
```